# Discordpy Say command with more than one line

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm having a problem with a say command, and it is that i can't send a well formated text.

I wanted to make it look like this:
[image]

But it answers with this:
[image]

Here is the code:

```
#COMMAND say
@commands.command()
@commands.has_any_role(*Say_Role)
async def say(self, ctx, *message):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    channel = ctx.channel
    await ctx.send(f"✅", delete_after=0.1)
    await channel.send(message)
```

What I need to do in order to make it look like the first image?

Comment: To get the message, I would just do something like:
message_content_to_post = ctx.message.content.replace("!say ","")
and then simply await ctx.send(message_content_to_post)

Comment: @Infinity I got an error: `RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback`

Comment: Seems like you haven't used await somewhere and have instead written it as if calling a synchronous function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the wrong way to use the consume rest behavior.

Doing `func(*args)` will make `args` into a tuple of arguments, like `('this', 'is', 'an', 'argument')`. [See more here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters#36908)

You're probably looking to make it a string:

```py
async def say(self, ctx, *, message: str):
    ...
```